# Downloading dSYM file from App Store Connect is not working as expected

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode9, dsym

I'm trying to download one dSYM file from App Store Connect for symbolicate crashes on Fabric Crashlytics. But when I try to download it I receive a stranger file with .dms extension which is not valid for symbolicate crashes on Crashlytics. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution for that. It is as simple as manually change the `.dms` extension to `.zip` and decompress the file. You should be able to get all the dSYMs that you want.

Answer (score 1):

The activity page in iTunes Connect indicates that there is currently a processing problem. I would wait for that message to go away before I start worrying about the dSYMS

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this myself trying to get the dsyms to upload to Sentry. You just have to give it a while after processing to finish whatever magic iTunes is doing behind the scenes. I waited 30 minutes and the dsym array downloaded as expected.

While the .dms can, indeed, be unzipped by changing the file ext to .zip as mentioned above, there's no guarantee that there won't be some changes made to the dsyms while they're in that post-processing state. So I now just